# Pattern matching list prefixes in Scala

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

I have questions regarding pattern matching of list prefixes (i.e. the first couple of elements of a list).

This compiles, but it does not work as expected:

```
  val l = List(1,2,3)

  val test = { m: List[Int] =>
    m match {
      case l :: tail => println("tail: "+tail.mkString(","))
      case _ => println("no match")
    }
  }

  test(List(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Output is `tail: 2,3,4,5`. I'd expect it to say either `tail: 4,5`, or to fail to match, or to fail at compile time. What makes this work as it does?

My second question is: How can I match a list prefix using a list? I know that this works as I expect:

```
      case 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: tail => println("tail: "+tail.mkString(","))
```

I have, however, my prefixes as lists, and cannot hard-code them. Is pattern matching even the right thing here?

I know I could do something like

```
    if (m startsWith l) {
      val tail = m drop l.size          
    }
```

But a long list of these seems rather inelegant, especially in Scala.

Comment: If prefix `List(1,2,6)` is matched against `List(1,2,3,4,5)`, what is your expected result? Is it `List(3,4,5)` or no match?

Comment: Good point. I'd expect no match.

Comment: Both top rated answers are great - StackOverflow needs a shared accept!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the output of your first code snippet, the `l` inside of the `match` is actually a new value that shadows the outer scoped `l` and captures `1` during execution.

The problem you are encountering is that `::` is the `unapply` for `List` to break it into exactly a single *head* value and the *tail*, deconstructing the linked list.

While there is a `:::` operation to go along with `:::` to concatenate two lists, it does not have a corresponding `unapply` which would let you use it in a pattern match in the way you desire.

Comment: +1 for actually addressing my question regarding the matching of `l` - I'm a bit embarrassed I haven't realized this myself.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible. Closest syntax i could propose based on this workaround:

```
import collection.SeqLike

implicit class PrefixMatcher[T](prefix: Seq[T]) {
  object then  {
    def unapply[S <: SeqLike[T,S]](seq: S): Option[S] =
      if (seq startsWith prefix) Some(seq drop prefix.length) else None
  }
}
```

Then you could use it as

```
val test: List[Int] => Unit = {
  case l.then(tail) => println("tail: " + tail.mkString(","))
  case _ => println("no match")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addresing the first part of your question: As @Arne mentions, `case l` is not being matched against your list, but captures a new list. For the former you'd need to enclose it on backticks, but even then I don't see how you can achieve what you want, the closes I can think of is:

```
 case `l` :+ x => println(s"tail is $s") //but this just works when the tail is just one element long.
```

For the final part of your question, maybe pattern matching is not the right thing to do here, how about:

```
 val prefixes = List (List (1,2,3), List(4,5,6)...)

 def findTail(li:List[Int]) =  prefixes.collectFirst{ case p if li.startsWith(p) => li.drop(p.size) } //Option[List[Int]]
```

This will find the tail for the first prefix that matches the `testList` or `None` if there was no match.You can easily generalize it to work with more than just `Int`s.